# What does HPE_INVALID_EOF_STATE mean

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, winston

Using hapi.js with a winston logger the messages we get every now and then is:

`data: {"bytesParsed":0,"code":"HPE_INVALID_EOF_STATE"}`

What does it mean and where does it come from?

Answer (score 5):

It is an error from the nodejs http parser, see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d006d6aa460bf9e11985cf2379484034d66aeb4e/deps/http_parser/http_parser.c#L664) for more details.  I am no c expert as to why you are hitting this error but have never encountered with hapi or node.  See [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5220) issue on an old version of node also for some more context.

Answer (score 3):

Within `HPE_INVALID_EOF_STATE`, `HPE` stands for HTTP PARSER ERROR and `EOF` is end of file.  You could read this as an HTTP parser error that encountered an unexpected end-of-file (or string).

So let's look a bit deeper.  When looking that [particular line](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d006d6aa460bf9e11985cf2379484034d66aeb4e/deps/http_parser/http_parser.c#L664) I see that the `HPE_INVALID_EOF_STATE` error happens when an HTTP packet of 0 bytes arrives.

It happens in the `http_parser_execute()` method and it's likely due to a malformed HTTP packet arriving.  It looks like it's been resolved in this case which was for an older version of Node.js:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5220